# How do I prevent unwanted object properties from the client in nestjs while updating an existing row in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nestjs, typeorm, class-validator

Creating a new user will ignore non-specified objects from `create-user.dto.ts`

However when I update the user it will add unwanted fields like this:

```
// update-user.dto.ts
import { IsEmail } from 'class-validator';
import { Address } from '../model/address';

export class UpdateUserDto {
  firstName: string;

  lastName: string;

  @IsEmail(undefined, { message: 'Not a valid e-mail' })
  email: string;

  username: string;

  password: string;

  addresses: Address[];
}
```

This is the update action from the user service

```
// user.service.ts
  async update(data: UpdateUserDto) {
    try {
      this.logger.log(data);
      const id = '5c6dd9852d4f441638c2df86';
      const user = await this.userRepository.update(id, data);

      return { message: 'Updated your information' };
    } catch (error) {
      this.logger.log(error);
      throw new HttpException('', HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
  }
```

And here is the user.controller.ts

```
  @Patch()
  @UsePipes(CustomValidationPipe)
  async update(@Body() data: UpdateUserDto) {
    return this.userService.update(data);
  }
```

The client patch data:

```
// Unwanted junk from client
{
  "email": "newemail@gmail.com",
  "junk": "junk"
}
```

The `email` will update properly but the row will have a new unwanted property `junk` with the value `junk`

Answer (score 31):

I'm assuming you are using `class-transformer`'s `validate` method in your `CustomValidationPipe`.

When you pass the `whitelist` option to it, `validate` will strip away all unknown (-> no annotation in your DTO class) properties:

```
validate(userUpdate, { whitelist: true })
```

If you want to throw a validation error instead of just stripping away unknown properties, you can additionally pass the `forbidNonWhitelisted` option.

```
validate(userUpdate, { whitelist: true, forbidNonWhitelisted: true });
```

In the case of an update, you probably also want to use `skipMissingProperties: true`, so that validate will not throw an error, when e.g. `lastName` is not part of the update.

---

Note, that you should annotate all properties in your dto class, for the validation to work properly:

```
@IsString()
lastName: string;

@ValidateNested()
@Type(() => Address)
address: Address
```

Comment: Excellent answer. Exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 19):

Not sure when this behavior/option was added to NestJS (perhaps it was added after the original question and accepted answer), but the best way to achieve unknown property stripping would be that:

```
app.useGlobalPipes(
  new ValidationPipe({
    whitelist: true,
  }),
);
```

That is it. By just making sure you have `whitelist: true` in your config, you won't be getting any unknown/invalid property.

You can also completely stop the request by setting another property called `forbidNonWhitelisted` to `true`.

More on that here: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation#stripping-properties

Answer (score 2):

For newbies like me who still wondering, here some easy way to implement it:

```
@UsePipes(new ValidationPipe({ whitelist: true }))
```

Put the decorator under decorator of methods (@Post, @Put , etc)

Both `UsePipe` and `ValidationPipe` are imported `@nestjs/common`

Answer (score 2):

If you also want to throw an error for unexpected properties it can be configured as follows:

```
app.useGlobalPipes(
 new ValidationPipe({
  whitelist: true,
  forbidNonWhitelisted: true,
  forbidUnknownValues: true
 })
);
```

An unexpected property will result in

```
{
 "statusCode": 400,
 "message": [
    "property XXX should not exist"
 ],
 "error": "Bad Request"
}
```

The discussion can be found [here](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator/issues/305#issuecomment-468009287)

Comment: How come this answer got 0 upvote before me? Exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: That is exactly what I was searching for. Thanks, man.

Answer (score -2):

I found the solution:

This is how user.service.ts update() should look like:

```
const user = await this.userRepository.create(data);
```

needs to be added before

```
await this.userRepository.update(id, user);
```

Here is the complete user.service.ts update()

```
  async update(data: UpdateUserDto) {
    this.logger.log(data);

    // added for testing purposes (id should be based on active user)
    const id = '5c6ef2c823bf4e3414d65cd0';
    const user = await this.userRepository.create(data);
    await this.userRepository.update(id, user);

    return { message: 'Updated your information' };
  }
```

Now any unwanted properties will not be added to the row